# iPhone: Update All address (Home, Work, Other) of contact

Tags: iphone, set, contacts, street-address

i am creating a new contact programmatically. it work well except address. following is the code to add a contact

```
ABAddressBookRef libroDirec = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef persona = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, tempSingle.firstName , nil);
        ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonLastNameProperty, tempSingle.lastName, nil);
        ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty, tempSingle.middleName, nil);

if([tempSingle.homeStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeState length]>0 || [tempSingle.homePostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeCountry length]>0 )
        {
            ABMutableMultiValueRef multiHome = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);

            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *homeStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.homeStreet1,tempSingle.homeStreet2];
            [addressDictionary setObject:homeStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homePostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            //[addressDictionary setObject:@"US" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];
            bool didAddHome = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiHome, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
            if(didAddHome)
            {
                ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiHome, NULL);
            }
            [addressDictionary release];
        }

        if([tempSingle.workStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.workStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.workCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.workState length]>0 || [tempSingle.workPostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.workCountry length]>0 )
        {
            ABMutableMultiValueRef multiWork = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);

            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *workStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.workStreet1,tempSingle.workStreet2];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:workStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workPostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            bool didAddWork = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiWork, addressDictionary1, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
            if(didAddWork)
            {
                ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiWork, NULL);
            }
            [addressDictionary1 release];
        }

        if([tempSingle.otherStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherState length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherPostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherCountry length]>0 )
        {
            ABMutableMultiValueRef multiOther = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);

            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *otherStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.otherStreet1,tempSingle.otherStreet2];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:otherStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherPostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            bool didAddOther = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiOther, addressDictionary2, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
            if(didAddOther)
            {
                ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiOther, NULL);
            }
            [addressDictionary2 release];
        }
ABAddressBookAddRecord(libroDirec, persona, nil);

        CFRelease(persona);
ABAddressBookSave(libroDirec, nil);
    CFRelease(libroDirec);
```

If i save only home address or only work address or only other address, then code works well. but if i save all address(Home, Work and Other) then only last address save to contacts.Please suggest how can i resolve this error
please suggest what is the wrong ?

Comment: What is the error message your getting??

Comment: There are no error message.Above code works well. first of all sorry for incomplete description. i also add the work and other address after home address so i get only last address detail(other address) when i see the contacts . now i am edit my original post

Answer (score 0):

the property identified by kABPersonAddressProperty can take just one value, which is of type ABMutableMultiValueRef, and this multivalue can contain many dictionaries in it with some label.

What you might need is probably this..

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiAddress = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);

if([tempSingle.homeStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeState length]>0 || [tempSingle.homePostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.homeCountry length]>0 )
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *homeStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.homeStreet1,tempSingle.homeStreet2];
            [addressDictionary setObject:homeStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homePostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary setObject:tempSingle.homeCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            //[addressDictionary setObject:@"US" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];
            bool didAddHome = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, NULL);
            if(!didAddHome)
            {
                NSLog(@"unable to add address");
            }
            [addressDictionary release];
        }

        if([tempSingle.workStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.workStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.workCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.workState length]>0 || [tempSingle.workPostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.workCountry length]>0 )
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *workStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.workStreet1,tempSingle.workStreet2];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:workStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workPostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary1 setObject:tempSingle.workCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            bool didAddWork = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary1, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
            if(!didAddWork)
            {
                NSLog(@"unable to add address");
            }
            [addressDictionary1 release];
        }

        if([tempSingle.otherStreet1 length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherStreet2 length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherCity length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherState length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherPostal length]>0 || [tempSingle.otherCountry length]>0 )
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSString *otherStreetAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tempSingle.otherStreet1,tempSingle.otherStreet2];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:otherStreetAddress forKey:(NSString *) kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherCity forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherState forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherPostal forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];
            [addressDictionary2 setObject:tempSingle.otherCountry forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
            bool didAddOther = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiAddress, addressDictionary2, kABOtherLabel, NULL);
            if(!didAddOther)
            {
                NSLog(@"unable to add address");
            }
            [addressDictionary2 release];
        }
ABRecordSetValue(persona, kABPersonAddressProperty, multiAddress, NULL);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(libroDirec, persona, nil);

CFRelease(persona);
ABAddressBookSave(libroDirec, nil);
CFRelease(libroDirec);
```